# APK signing error : Failed to read key from keystore

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I'm developing android app under intellij and gradle. and using following way to generate keystore file:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then used the keystore file in build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    robert {
        storePassword 'robert'
        storeFile file('/Users/bournewang/Documents/Project/android.keystore')
        keyPassword 'robert'
        keyAlias 'mike'
    }
}
```

when finally trying to generate signed apk file: ./gradlew assembleRelease

it gives the error:

Execution failed for task ':Myexample:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key from keystore

Comment: adding --info and --stacktrace to the gradlew command line should give you more info that might help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I was facing this because the "key alias" I typed in didn't exist in the keystore. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28119723/1276636) helped me out.

Comment: I just deleted the key and it generated a new one

Comment: Changing Gradle JDK verison helped me try this -> [View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000947/13651898)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Check your keystore file for first, in you example you creating file with name my-release-key.keystore. If its correct and really present in folder  `Users/bournewang/Documents/Project` check alias, in your example it is **-alias alias_name**, but in config you specified alias **mike**

Answer (score 92):

In order to find out what's wrong you can use gradle's `signingReport` command.

On mac:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

On Windows:

```
gradlew signingReport
```

Comment: +1 thank you for that hint! This way I figured out, that when running signingReport it did list my release signing config, but only the Store location, the variant, the config and the alias. It was missing Sha1, md5 and the valid until. The reason was: my alias was wrong : ) - so if above command lists the entire set of info, you should be all set (variant, config, store, alias, md5, sha1, valid until), if not, make sure you have passwords, keystore and alias set up correctly in your project's build.gradle file

Comment: Running this it is showing that:

`Variant: release
Config: none`

Is my .keystore deleted?

Comment: thanks a bunch! gradlew is located directly in ones android studio project directory. Calling signingReport reveals that the debug-key's alias is actually "AndroidDebugKey"...

Comment: Or for me it was (in the android platform director) ./gradlew.bat signingReport

Comment: I had the wrong alias and got a result with no errors but not the desired data, so for those who at first didn't know how o interpret the report, your key MUST be print with SHA1 and MD5 values next to it to consider it correct.

Comment: This saved me a lot

Comment: Guys i've got this error and i don't know how to solved it.

Error: Failed to read key android-production from store "/Users/rodrigodiasdefigueiredo/Desktop/z-mobile/android/app/android-production.keystore": Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely that your key alias does not exist for your keystore file.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119162/import-key-store-from-eclipse-to-android-studio/28119723#28119723) should fix your signing issue ;)

Comment: why there no option in my android studio ver 4.0.1

Answer (score 6):

Removing `double-quotes` solve my problem, now its:

```
DEBUG_STORE_PASSWORD=androiddebug
DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS=androiddebug
DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD=androiddebug
```

Comment: Where did you remove?? In the sky??

Answer (score 4):

In my case, while copying the text from other source it somehow included the space at the end of clipboard entry. That way the key password had a space at the end.

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio go to `Build > Clean Project` then re-generate signed APK using `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK...` and then clear password-fields and re-enter your passwords

Comment: For those who typed alias wrong in the first time, and keeps getting the same error even if they changed the alias can try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked.

1. Go to `<your_app_name>/android`.
2. On the terminal use `./gradlew signingReport` for Mac OS and `gradlew signingReport` for Windows.
3. Check if each element of each task has a **Variant, Config, Store, Alias, MD5, SHA1, SHA-256, Valid until**. If so you should be good.
4. If any of the above are absent then try to regenerate the key store by following the instructions on this [page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android).
5. Copy the key store file and paste it inside `<your_app_name>/android/app`.

Some things that I was doing wrong while generating the key store file were.

1. Using quotations on `MYAPP_UPLOAD_..._PASSWORD`'s.

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD="Password123"
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD="Password123"
```

2. I used **\J4ct@RD** as a password and it did not work. I later changed the password to something that was just aplphanumeric and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it happened in Debug build variant. So I closed the android studio. deleted the `debug.keystore` and `debug.keystore.lock` files and open the project again. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For someone not using the signing configs and trying to test out the Cordova Release command by typing all the parameters at command line, you may need to enclose your passwords with single quotes if you have special characters in your password

```
cordova run android --release -- --keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword='password' --alias=alias_name --password='password'
```

Answer (score 1):

The big thing is either the alias or the other password is wrong. Kindly check your passwords and your issue is solved. Incase you have forgotten password, you can recover it from the androidStuido3.0/System/Log ... Search for the keyword password and their you are saved

Comment: Could you kindly confirm if the Log file i should be looking at is this == idea.log , at the path == C:\Users\xxxx\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\log\idea.log

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct the folliwn

- keystore **file path**
- keystore **alies name**
- keystore **password**

keystore in **android/key.properties**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in my case for some reason, after updating android studio to the last stable version, the password that was always by default got changed, i just had to set correct password again and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you generated the keyfile, `keytool` might refer to a different binary, running on a different JVM version. These are not necessarily compatible, try adjusting the versions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any one of the parameter, not just the file name or alias - for me it was the Key Password.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error today.

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key news from store "E:\keystore\news.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I had same key password and key store password. But **i wrote a wrong password**.

Answer (score 0):

for me was need to update the key when I transfer the source code to another PC

the steps
using UI

files ==> Project Structure... ==> Modules ==>Sining Configs

[image]