# android google map issues

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently building an android app. I understand the basics and I did a number of apps but now my project is bigger. My app include a number of screens with NavigationDrawer included which forces me to use an extension of Fragment class on every class I want to be displayed on my application. 
Here is my problem -some time ago I create an app a simple one page google maps screen and it works just fine. I want to do the same thing on the app I am currently working on but all it gives me when I go to the page is the google log at the bottom left screen and the rest is grey like view (no map is displayed).I searched for solution in a lot of places including this site and I could get as an answer was that it might have to do with my API key given to me by google.I ckecked that and I am pretty sure it is not from the key because I applied it on my one page google map app and it worked perfect.I also have all the permissions needed I checked that like 6 times.So my conclusion is there is something in the code that is preventing the map to be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class guide extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container,
                false);

        return v;
    }

    class HoldFragmentPlace extends FragmentActivity{

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        public HoldFragmentPlace(){

        }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container,
                false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

        private void setUpMap() {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }


    }

}
```

I need that Fragment extension for my NavigationDrawer to work so I create an inner class and applied the code for the map there.

Here is what I have in my manifest:

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission         android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And here is my xml for the map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="-470dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried a few other variations of the java code some of them does not include inner class and the result is still the same.I am either missing something very fundamental or I am misunderstanding some conception about Android.If you have read all that thank you for the spared time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the APK signing. You have to assign a debug API key in testing and a Release API key when releasing APK. Insert the correct API key, clean and rebuild your project.

I've been there a year a go and I can assure that this was the problem. Double check your key and if it's a debug or release key.

Another thing to check is the package name of your app... 
Let me know if you did and still get the grey view instead of the

**UPDATE:**

I was trying to include everything when I realized that your problem is only in the signing phase.

You only need to get the **SHA-1 fingerprint** of the **debug keystore** and put it in your API Key dialog. And trust me there's nothing I can write that can be more clear and informative than the Google documentation.

Follow the steps in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) to get the **debug certificate** and the **SHA-1 fingerprint**.

**UPDATE 2:**

In order to get the SHA-1 of the keystore you might check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) .

Comment: 04-15 12:42:28.960    1961-2088/********************E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-15 12:42:28.960    1961-2088/****************E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: *****************
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): ********************************

Comment: and also E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Comment: So it's telling you in the error message, there's an authorization problem, just as I said earlier check your package name, a missing letter might be the problem. Also make sure that the API key you already generated is a debug key. Can you please confirm doing this and see what happens?

Comment: so right now I should create a debug key store right?why I can't simply create a release one? and if I will be needing my SHA1 I have a little problem I don't have a debug filder in my android folder

Comment: For release key you have to generate a Release APK file to be uploaded to the play store, that's another phase of development. And yes you have to generate a debug API key. Do it and let me know what happens.

Comment: Right well my package name is correct as for the already generated API key when I was building the app I created a map activity which generated xml file in which there was some SHA1 code.I used that to generate my key and I assume that this is a debug key,other than that I don't know how to check if it really is one.Also when I go to gradle.app on signingConfigs{} the method is empty  .I found in my .android folder a debug.keystore file.Do you know how can I access it by any chance to see the key?

Comment: I'll post a a detailed answer of how to setup a working android map, from a to z.

Comment: Thank you! In the mean time I created a new debug keystore from File->Project Structure and now my gradle have the following     signingConfigs {
        map {
            keyAlias 'map'
            keyPassword '*******'
            storeFile file('C:/Android Key Store/key_store.jks')
            storePassword '*****'
        }
    }

Comment: I also set it in BuildTypes to start automatically every time.But now when I run it I have this error at run time Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key from keystore

Comment: I'm editing my answer, and regarding the new error here's a thread were someone had the same problem and got it solved 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore

Comment: @user2961062 check the edit, and if I could help please dedicate a little bit of your time to up-vote my answer.

Comment: right when I run my cmd and direct it to my newly created keystore and type this     keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android                                                               I get this message: keytool is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: I've updated the answer, it's okay to fail with this several time, as most of us do fail at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some part missing :

(1) Declare permission to use `MAPS_RECEIVE` :

```
<permission android:name="com.example.yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<!-- after declare use this -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

(2) Missing Declare gms version variable :

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

(3) The API_KEY may have some problem with generation :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key" />
```

Please check with above 3 suspects first : then if still error is there you can re-confirm steps to enable Google Maps from [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)

Check things related to API_KEY carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can use SupportMapFragment to display map in your fragment.

The xml should be changed to

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
 android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_marginTop="-470dp"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and your class would be like below

```
public class guide extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);

    ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMapAsync (new OnMapReadyCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
                    this.mMap = map;
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    setUpMap();
                }
            });


    return v;
}

private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

}
```

Note: Please update your google play services if you dont find the getMapAsync method for your SupportMapFragment.