# Get signed release apk?

Tags: android, apk

I have got this error while signing apk
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFlavorDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.app.asiannews'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageFlavorDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key android  from store "C:\Users\hp-pc\.android\debug.keystore": No key with alias 'android ' found in keystore C:\Users\hp-pc\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: Now i get the above mentioned error ? @Kuffs

Comment: Add your keystore to your app folder.

Comment: just type the error text into google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore

Comment: thank you fr that.. now the prblm is:    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_flavorDebugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':volley'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':volley:classpath'.
         > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
           Searched in the following locations:
               https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom