# Android Studio build generate signed apk keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, android, keystore

I'm trying to generate the update packages for an Android application, however the following error occurs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key pasep from store "C:\Users...\PASEP.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance! Hugs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK signing error : Failed to read key from keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore)

Comment: @kimkevin I tried this and dont work for me. Thanks

Comment: I have this problem in Android Studio 3.0 rc2, but it works in Android Studio 2.3.3... Which version are you using?

Comment: @OveStoerholt Hi, Im using Android Studio version 2.2.2.

Comment: I just tried the new Android Studio 3.0 and now I get the same error.