# Why when switching from build variant release back to debug do I receive decryption based error and can't develop/debug?

Tags: android, debugging, encryption, build, release

**Problem:** After attempting (1st time ever) to create an Android build variant release, I discovered a couple potential bugs that should be fixed. When I switch the build variant back to debug I receive the following error? I'm not sure how to fix this? I understand it has to do with the signing but again, not sure how to resolve it and actually not sure why it is wanting do this? Just naive as a new learner I guess.

```
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key KEY1RDB from store "C:\Users\<user>\.android\my-key-store\research_db.jks": keystore password was incorrect
```

and...

```
Cause: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

**What I think happened:** I think the `.jks` file was overwritten as a release and changed the password... if that is a possibility?

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to switch back to debugging and development. After going through the motions of signing and releasing (within the IDE). I can't build anything.

**What I've done:** I don't know if there is way for me to correct or correctly enter the password? I naively deleted my debug and release apks and bundles wondering if that was a cause. I tried to clean and rebuild. Again, just really not sure what to do. I don't know if just pulling the complete project back down from GIT is a viable solution or not. Just need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer pretty quick and could have deleted this post but for the sake of others like myself, I thought it better to post. However, my solution was to use the following link. Thankfully, I keep good notes on my keystore information and was able to reopen my project.

[APK signing error : Failed to read key from keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore)