# gradlew signingreport missing keystore while getting sha 1 for release mode flutter apk

Tags: flutter, build, keystore, sha1, gradlew

I was testing release mode of my app and the firebase auth is not working, so i google it and find out that i have to register SHA1 for release mode, and to get it we need keysotre file  which i generated using command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias AndroidReleaseKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

i was taking help of this documentaion: [Click here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)

and [THIS STACKOVERFLOW QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore)

but now when i run `./gradlew signingreport` i am getting this

[image: getting somthing unespacted result]

i want the SHA1 key for release mode can anyone help me through it and also my android studio is not working fine so give me answers that doesn't require it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just look the output of `./gradlew signingreport` in the image, and you will know where I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Path c\file , And upgrade Project --flutter Upgrade or Update , After  Retry.

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The only mistake is that I put `\` in store file path and when I use `/` instead it worked as I wanted.